# I can't update anything on an old Mac OSX Leopard 10.5.8

Tags: macos, mac, osx-leopard

I'm trying to help a family friend with an issue with their old mac. They can't view any videos or see anything on YouTube. When I go to YouTube on their mac, it says Safari is out of date. So I tried updating Safari and checked for other updates, but suspiciously it says everything is up to date. I also tried downloading a version of Chrome and Firefox that would work with their old Mac, but after downloading it also suspiciously said that neither were compatible.

Another suspicious thing is that some https websites can't be accessed while others can be.

When I asked what changed since the last time, they said that they let their kid on the mac and they "hit a bunch of buttons". Nothing really seemed too out of place other than a couple of new folders made.

These are the specs of the mac:

macOSX Leopard
Version 10.5.8

Processor: 2 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo
Memory: 2GB 667MHZ DDR2
Graphics: TM

Comment: The OS is 15 years old & hasn't been supported in a decade. It will have certificate & security issues & will not be able to connect to the App Store to find updates. Knowing precisely which Mac it is would let us see how much further it could be updated, though it's not going to be far. If you're not sure, see [Ultimate Mac Lookup](https://everymac.com/ultimate-mac-lookup/)

Comment: I figured as such and already let them know it was quite old. They really want to keep their old system and were pretty insistent it was fine before letting their kid on it, which is a bit of an issue but if I tell them there's nothing that can be done I'll definitely reinforce that again. I'll see if I can grab the serial to look up.

Comment: That Mac should be upgradeable to at least 10.6 (Snow Leopard) or 10.7 (Lion) (I actually prefer 10.6 in many ways). It may be a bit interesting to find an installer, since 10.6 came on a DVD, and 10.7 was an App Store download (and the App Store wasn't added until 10.6.6). Possibly useful info [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/378302/snow-leopard-clean-install) and [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309399). In they can get to at least 10.6, Jonathan Alland has some [useful software](https://jonathanalland.com/old-osx-projects.html) that may help.